# PHP json_encode data returned to AJAX call goes to fail and not done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Scenario: I have a php script which outputs data in json_encoded array, and an index html page with javascript which calls the php script via AJAX and handles the results.

Problem: AJAX call goes to `.fail` instead of `.done` even though it's getting a 200 response code and the responseText is json_encoded array.

After struggling with this I'm looking to you for help, *not flames and unwarranted downvotes*; I've researched this but the similar questions haven't resolved the issue.

**getDomains.php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$domains = array();
$domains[] = array('domainID' => 1, 'domainName' => 'alpha.com');
$domains[] = array('domainID' => 2, 'domainName' => 'beta.com');
echo json_encode($domains);
?>
```

**getDomains.php output in browser:**

```
[{"domainID":"1","domainName":"alpha.com"},{"domainID":"2","domainName":"beta.com"}]
```

**index.html/ajax.js:**

```
<script>
// Ajax execute
var go = $.ajax({
    url: 'getDomains.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(results) {
    console.debug('callAPI done');
    console.debug(results);
})
.fail(function(msg) {
    console.debug('callAPI fail');
    console.debug(msg);
})
.always(function() {
});
</script>
```

When I visit index.html I see `callAPI fail` message in console.log.

```
callAPI fail
Object { ...
    responseText: "[{"domainID":"1","domainName":"alpha.com"},{"domainID":"2","domainName":"beta.com"}]"
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
```

Comment: Ok so I copied my example to a new project and the above works fine... :'( I guess the problem is somewhere else in my application...